# Find the moment generating function of a discrete random variable given its probability mass function

Tags: statistics, moment-generating-functions

Say $Y$ is a random variable with support on $(1, 2, 3, \ldots ) $
and has the PMF:

$$\frac{C}{2^x}$$

How would you find the MGF from here and how would you arrange your answer so that it is not in sum notation?

Answer (score 0):

First we consider that PMF must sum up to unity so $(P_y(Y) = \frac{1}{2^y})$ for $y \in \mathbb N$:
$$\sum_{y=1}^{\infty}\frac{C}{2^y}=1 \Rightarrow C \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=1 \Rightarrow C = 1$$

Then by definition of MGF we see that ($i=\sqrt{-1}$):
$$\Phi_Y(\omega) = \mathbb{E}\{ e^{i\omega y} \}= \sum_{y=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i\omega y}}{2^y} = \frac{\frac{e^{i\omega}}{2}}{1-\frac{e^{i\omega}}{2}}=\frac{e^{i\omega}}{2-e^{i\omega}}$$

Also we have the geometric series formula:
for a complex number $z$ with $|z|<1$ we have:
$$\sum_{i=a}^{N}z^n = S = z^a+z^{a+1} +...z^N$$
$$\sum_{i=a}^{N}z^{n+1} = zS = z^{a+1}+z^{a+2} +...z^{N+1}$$
$$zS-S = (z-1)S = z^{N+1}-z^a \Rightarrow S  = \frac{z^{N+1}-z^a}{z-1}= \frac{z^a-z^{N+1}}{1-z}$$
When $N\rightarrow\infty$ we have $|z|^{N+1}\rightarrow 0$ and the formula becomes $$S=\frac{z^a}{1-z}$$
For above consider the case $a=1$. In first one $z=\frac{1}{2}$ and in the second $z = \frac{e^{i\omega}}{2}$

Also it can be interpreted as the discrete Fourier's transform of the sequence of the PMF which can be obtained from z-transform, also.

Comment: Could you please specify your steps in rearranging from sum notation to fractions? I think there may be a formula I am not familiar with.

Comment: Why do you have $i $? @K.K.McDonald

Comment: because the sequence of PMF is not even and hence the MGF will have imaginary part too. A sequence $s[n]$ is even if:
$$1)\text{it's domain is symmetric around}  \quad n=0$$
$$2)s[n] = s[-n]$$

Answer (score 0):

By equating the total probability to unity, it can be shown that $C=1$.

Then, by definition,
\begin{eqnarray*}
M_{X}(t)&=& E(e^{tX})=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}e^{tX}P(X=x)=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{e^t}{2}\right)^x\\
&=&\left(\dfrac{e^t}{2} + \left(\dfrac{e^t}{2}\right)^{2} + \left(\dfrac{e^t}{2}\right)^{3} + \cdots \right)\\
&=& \dfrac{e^t}{2} \left( 1 + \left(\dfrac{e^t}{2}\right) + \left(\dfrac{e^t}{2}\right)^{2} + \cdots \right)\\
&=&\dfrac{e^t}{2}\cdot \dfrac{1}{1-e^t/2}\\
M_{X}(t)&=&\dfrac{e^t}{2-e^t}
\end{eqnarray*}